# purrr::discard NA dates

Tags: r, purrr

Say I have a POSIX vector

```
x <- strptime(c("2017-01-30", ""), "%Y-%m-%d")
x
[1] "2017-01-30 EET" NA
```

and I want to drop NA dates with `purrr::discard`:

```
> library(purrr)
> discard(x, is.na)
Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector
```

Could anybody please explain why it throws an error?

For example, for

```
y <- c(1, NA)
```

it works well:

```
> discard(y, is.na)
[1] 1
```

Comment: I think that the function `discard` doesn't like the POSIXlt class, but I am not sure. It works if you convert x to character.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will exactly answer your question, but I was able to use the `discard` function by modifying the code a little.  Here's what I did:

```
date1 <- readr::parse_date(c("2017-01-30", "2017-02-03", " "))
date2 <- readr::parse_date(c("2016-01-30", "", "2016-02-03"))
df <- tibble(date1, date2)
df 

# A tibble: 3 x 2
       date1      date2
      <date>     <date>
1 2017-01-30 2016-01-30
2 2017-02-03         NA
3         NA 2016-02-03
```

Since `keep` and `discard` both work with vectors, it looks like data has to be handed to them in a specific way, which is why I think the `map` function works better at supplying `discard` with the data in the way that it likes.

```
map_df(df, discard, is.na)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
       date1      date2
      <dttm>     <dttm>
1 2017-01-30 2016-01-30
2 2017-02-03 2016-02-03
```

It also works if you want to use `strptime` as well:

```
date1 <- strptime(c("2017-01-30", "2017-02-03", ""), "%Y-%m-%d")
date2 <- strptime(c("2016-01-30", "", "2016-02-03"), "%Y-%m-%d")
df <- data.frame(date1, date2)
df

       date1      date2
1 2017-01-30 2016-01-30
2 2017-02-03       <NA>
3       <NA> 2016-02-03

map_df(df, discard, is.na)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
       date1      date2
      <dttm>     <dttm>
1 2017-01-30 2016-01-30
2 2017-02-03 2016-02-03
```

You can't create a tibble with the `POSIXlt` class though, and if you notice, after running the `map_df` function the date-time objects are converted to POSIXct.

Hopefully someone else with deeper `purrr` knowledge can answer the specific question about the error message--I thought you might want some workaround meantime, however.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution fails when these two columns have different number of NAs. And if we talk about workaround, `x[!is.na(x)]` works well, so the question was more why `discard` fails. And I think I actually figured it out: what you see as a POSIXlt vector of length n is a list of 11 vectors each of length n underneath - just type e.g. `map(x, identity)` to see it.

Comment: But nevertheless, thanks for your answer - now I know that POSIXlt is converted to POSIXct in data frames and POSIXct doesn't have such a structure so it can be handled well with discard. (`data.frame(x)[[1]] %>% map(identity)`)